# how to skip object when submitchanges in ado.net

Tags: c#, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm using ado.net entity data model. I have 2 object `User` `Organization`
My problem is

```
    User user=new User();

    ...

    Organization org=new Organization()

    db.Organizations.AddObject(org);

    db.SubmitChanges(); // Problem is here. Because datacontext try to save user object. user object some field is empty. I don't need to save user here. How to skip user object from submitchanges

    user.organization=org;

db.SubmitChanges(); // I need to save user object here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **using** statement to scope out your data context.

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but something like this?

```
Organization org=new Organization();
User user = new User();

using (var ctx = new YourContext())
{
   ctx.Organizations.InsertOnSubmit(org);
   ctx.SubmitChanges();
   user.Organization = org;    
}

using (var newCtx = new YourContext())
{
   // code to persist user 
}
```